# Render HTML from JSON datasource in Kendo Grid Column using Vue.js

Tags: html, json, vue.js, kendo-grid

Trying to render HTML data in kendo Grid column using Vue.js. 
Code Snippets are as below: 
JSON data- [image]

Template - [image]

Can anybody suggest how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the hyperlinks from JSON using props in kendo-grid in vue js.
Please find the below screenshots.

[KendoUI.vue page]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6eFw.png

[JSON DATA] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd9ww.png